# Deploying Two Web Frameworks under same domain

Tags: vue.js, deployment, configuration, vercel, sveltekit

I have an existing vue js application deployed to xyz.com. Now i developed another project with sveltekit which integrates with the vue js application . Now how do i deploy them to the same domain. so that i can access all the login informations  and user cookie.How do i acheive thie

```
xyz/-> vuejs app
xyz/svelte / -> sveltekit app
```

i used vercel [rewrites](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-serve-multiple-projects-under-a-single-domain) to serve both my apps but the problem is static assets , The vue assets does not seem to load when we use it like it , so i am only getting the blank html , without the css and js assets

```
xyz/-> vuejs app
xyz/svelte / -> sveltekit app
```